# Congratulations! Ethereum is graduating!

Tags: discussion

You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Ethereum met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

What does this mean exactly? Graduation works in two phases. Starting today, you'll receive the following benefits:

- You will start having an election for moderators. This will in fact be starting this week with a question collection session coming at 20:00 UTC (so, less than 2 hours from this posting)
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name. It's already gone!
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will soon be able to select your own community ads. These will go up later in the week.

The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, so instead of making you wait to receive all the parts of graduation at once, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. We think we've hammered out most of the bugs in the process,, but there are still likely to be some left -  so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: Are question migration paths not generally variable already (or is that just because I'm a moderator)?

Comment: We do not setup migrations as a direct user close option going to non-graduated sites because this can interfere with the natural growth of the site. I don't have numbers on me, but the lower barrier to migration is pretty impactful from what I remember. Moderator migration is always available though.

Comment: This has been an essential resource so far!

Answer (score 38):

We were working so hard and finally the day has come!

I would like to thank the Stack Exchange team for giving us the chance to field-test the site with a private and public beta, Roman Mandeleil for proposing Ethereum at [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704/ethereum), Hudson Jameson & Joris Bontje & *eth* for moderating the site, and all the users contributing questions, answers, tags, wikis, votes, flags, and everything else! Thanks for making this possible!

Comment: Thanks for all your work and promotion of the ethereum stackexchange. IMHO this is very important for the future of Ethereum and one of the good counter-weights to all the BS that also going on in this space! Big up!!

Comment: Awesome. Congrats!

Comment: Congratulations! Happy to see all your hard work rewarded

Comment: Well done!!! Awesome job :D

Comment: It's a great news !

Comment: Good work guys! :-)

Comment: Congrats, great job !

Answer (score 31):

In addition to 5chdn's post, thank you to 5chdn!!  It's safe to say that without 5chdn's leadership and drive, site graduation would not have come at this time and so quickly.  Been a privilege and pleasure working with 5chdn (sometimes we don't agree 100% but that is much much less than all the other collaboration done).  Since moderator elections are self-nominations (no one else can nominate him) let's hope 5chdn will be available :)

Thank you again to everyone else in the community for your contributions!  Let's keep it up!

Comment: Completely agree - thank you 5chdn! :-)

Comment: I would also like to thank @RichardHorrocks!  (And hope that he considers nominating himself for the elections :) )

Comment: Thanks very much @eth :-) I'll certainly consider a nomination :-) But whoever becomes the new set of moderators, I'm sure we'll all be in good hands - everyone around here is genuinely lovely :-)

Comment: Good work 5chdn

Answer (score 10):

Hip Hip Hoora :D, Congratulations.

the best news i've got today ( as the crypto market crashed ^^).

with such great team the ethereum.stackexchange deserves to be promoted(a high answering rate and active meta).
As @eth said 5chdn has played a key role in this promotion, thanks 5chdn and thanks everyone else who made this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Not surprising :) Great move guys!

This was bound to happen and I am very glad this happened. I think it will be great way to support the Ethereum community, which is growing every minute and only will continue to expand further.