# Is our site configured correctly for users to create new tags?

Tags: support

New tags seem to be created by users without [1500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).   Here is [example1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54736/why-is-checks-effects-interactions-pattern-called-checks-effects-interactions-pa), [example2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56158/erc725-smart-contract-for-self-sovereign-identity-management) and [another](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52606/casper-ffg-and-casper-ghost-name-motivation).

Is our site configured correctly?  How can our site be configured like Stack Overflow requiring 1500 rep?  Is there any chance that tags created by users with insufficient rep, be removed for now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one you're looking at is Stack Overflow's privilege, which has <s>graduated</s> a site-specific design, and thus they have "designed" rep threshold. Moreover, the threshold for creating new tags on SO is customized to 1500 rep while normal sites only needs 300.

However, Ethereum, while it has graduated, it is still using [public beta threshold](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) because it hasn't had its site design yet, and they only need [150 reps](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) instead.

This is by-design, as mentioned on [this site's graduation post](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/474/3343):

> The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, **which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege.**
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

For more information: [FAQ - Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/241919).

Comment: Thanks. I've read a little https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290359/how-long-until-graduated-sites-get-a-new-site-design-and-increased-privileges-th which mentions https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290359/how-long-until-graduated-sites-get-a-new-site-design-and-increased-privileges-th   Roughly does it look like the Law site is next for design and then us?

Comment: @eth regarding site design.... unfortunately, as far as I (and some other) know, there's no site design since October 2016 (Signal Processing), so any future planning would be speculation unless SE staff answered it directly... it *would* be great if they could continue creating new site designs after the [new unified theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312365/241919) though, but alas...